# How to remove a chrome.app.window.onMinimize event listener?

Tags: javascript, events, listener

I have the following piece of code in javascript, creating an event listener :

```
chrome.app.window.onMinimized.addListener(callbackFunction());
```

At some point I need to remove this listener, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These docs are a bit whack, you should be able to just do `removeListener`: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#type-Event

Answer (score -2):

```
chrome.app.window.onMinimized.removeEventListener(callbackFunction());
```

[See example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp)